# Why can't I get font awesome to work in an ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, font-awesome, content-security-policy

I am having an issue adding font awesome to my ASP.NET Core MVC (ASP.NET Core 2) application. I am simply trying to add the CSS library called font awesome to my MVC project. I have tried two approaches

1) Adding the font awesome CDN like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

but when I add the CDN I get the CSP errors in Chrome

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So I tried adding the correct meta tags. I tried MANY combinations and nothing seemed to work. For example,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; " />
```

I was still getting errors related to CSP in Chrome.

2) The second approach I took was to add the font awesome CSS file in my project. I did this and then added the corresponding reference like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

When I did this I got the following errors despite the file being in the correct location and being referenced correctly:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:5000/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:5000/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 404 (Not Found)
```

I looked into this issue and found that it could be related to the static file handler. I then modified the `app.UseStaticFiles()` to take an options parameter like this:

```
StaticFileOptions staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions();
FileExtensionContentTypeProvider typeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff2"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff2", "application/font-woff2");
}

if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff", "application/font-woff");
}

if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".ttf"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".ttf", "application/font-ttf");
}
staticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = typeProvider;
app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

But I still got the error above.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I can add font awesome through its CDN or add the font awesome CSS file in my application if need be.

Comment: Your document’s being served with a Content-Security-Policy HTTP header that’s relatively strict in that it has `default-src 'self'` but no `style-src` at all. Then you’re specifying a different less-strict policy using a `meta` element in the document itself. But the way CSP works when you specify multiple policies is, the most-strict policy always wins. So your browser’s basically ignoring your `meta` policy and just using the policy specified in the HTTP header. The only solution in this case is: change the server code so it sends a different value for the Content-Security-Policy header

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? The only place I specified Content-Security-Policy is in the metadata tag in the server side rendered HTML page.What else would be modifying the header? I did try a second approach but have since removed the code. Also, if you put this in an answer that works or leads to a working answer I'll accept it.

Comment: As far as elaboration, I think if you look at the response headers for your document, you should find a Content-Security-Policy header. To see those headers, open the Network pane in your browser devtools and reload the document and examine the response there — or else use Postman or `curl` or some other command-line tool that lets you examine the HTTP headers for the response. So if you do find a Content-Security-Policy header there, but you can’t where/how your server-side code is adding it to the response, I think you probably want to post a new separate question to get help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That policy quoted in the error message in the question has `default-src 'self'` but the policy shown from your `meta` element doesn’t. That seems to indicate your document’s being served with a policy in a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header in addition to the one in the `meta`.

And that other policy is relatively strict in that it has `default-src 'self'` and no `style-src`. So while you’re specifying another less-strict policy using that `meta`, the problem’s that the way CSP works when you specify multiple policies is, the most-strict policy always wins. So your browser’s basically ignoring your `meta` policy and just using the policy specified in the HTTP header.

The solution is: find the place in the server code which is adding that `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header, and either change it so it has the exact policy you want, or else remove that part of the server code altogether, and instead just set the policy using the `meta` element.

Comment: I didn't realize these headers were being manually set by my back end. Once I removed them everything worked.